# How to get the sum column values in laravel in model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I was told that I can get the sum of certain column values using a function in model instead of doing this code with foreach :

```
$orders = Order::where('place_id',1)->select('delivery_fees')->get()->toArray();
        $orderArray = [];
        foreach ($orders as $order)
        {
            $orderArray[] = $order['delivery_fees'];
        }
$deliveryCostTotal = array_sum($orderArray);
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: use `array_push` to push data in array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use laravel  sum function

```php
$deliveryCostTotal = Order::where('place_id',1)->sum('delivery_fees');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#aggregates

Answer (score 2):

Using Mysql SUM

```php
$deliveryCostTotal = Order::where('place_id',1)->selectRaw('SUM(delivery_fees) AS cost_total')->value('cost_total');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this please

```
$deliveryFees = Order::where('place_id',1)->sum('delivery_fees');
```

Answer (score 0):

As your problem is solved but I am considering my answer as clearing your confusion in `array_sum` and adding data in array . because you are only setting value to array and overriding it, use `array_push` to add data in array.

```
 $orders = Order::where('place_id',1)->select('delivery_fees')->get()->toArray();
            $orderArray = [];
            foreach ($orders as $order)
            {
               array_push($orderArray,$order['delivery_fees']);
            }
    $deliveryCostTotal = array_sum($orderArray);
```